# How do you use Ruby on Rails for science (if applicable)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bioinformatics

We do research in systems biology. We prefer to use existing data sets, because collecting new biological data is expensive. Thus, a lot of the scripts we write are little more than transformations of one data set into another.

Eventually, we put our results online -- and more and more journals are requiring this sort of thing.

So it was no great leap for me to try using Rails for my projects. I can set up easily reproducible experiments, transform data step by step through database tables (e.g. using rake), and display results using gems like [flotomatic](http://github.com/xdotcommer/flotomatic) and the gnuplot. If I need something to run very quickly, I can even write a custom gem in C++ using [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org/), or parallelize using [starling](http://github.com/starling/starling) and [workling](http://github.com/purzelrakete/workling).

Eventually, I started to wonder if anyone else was using Rails to do bioinformatics or science in general.

I thought, "If I were a science research Rails gem, what would I do?"

What extra features would such a gem have? Perhaps a Migration adaptation into a rake-able pipeline? Maybe more advanced graphing features? Built-in background jobs?

Comment: Should this be a community wiki?

Comment: @Jasper: I don't have the reputation to edit a community wiki, but I'd like to participate.

Comment: It wasn't as much a question to you as it was a question to whoever was passing by with enough rep to make your post a community wiki (and if I 'm not mistaken, you can edit a community wiki if you were the original poster). The idea is that you don't get reputation for it, and it is usually applied to question that don't have a single answer (or which will have a different answer for each user as in your case or question which are clearly subjective)

Answer (score 4):

For Bioinformatics, see http://bioruby.org

Comment: I am aware of bioruby, but this question is really about Rails.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Pierre. I think bioruby is the right place.  Many (most?) bioruby users/developers use rails, making rails a natural extension to the bioruby project.

Here's an incomplete list of bioruby code for rails:

- Run bioruby console in a rail app - http://bioruby.open-bio.org/wiki/BioRubyOnRails
- ActiveRecord (Rails default ORM) classes for Ensembl - bioruby-annex.rubyforge.org/
- Plugin for Uniprot db - bioruby.g.hatena.ne.jp/nakao_mitsuteru/20070410/uniprot_on_active_record_plugin
- CHADO/Bioruby integration effort - github.com/robsyme/RubyCHADO

sorry about the messed up links, but as a new user I can't post more than a single link :(

Answer (score 3):

I've used Michael Barton's [organized_experiments](https://github.com/michaelbarton/organised_experiments) before. It works quite nicely once you replace DataMapper with ActiveRecord.

Comment: Ha! Fair enough. At the time DataMapper seemed like the new hotness so it was an excuse to give it a whirl. I retrospect AR was always going to be more supported and stable.